# C++ : Changing the value of a fixed-sized 3D array in a function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have a stack-allocated fixed-sized 3D array declared as such:

```
ofVec2f geometry[24][30][4];
```

I need to pass this to a function to updates all the ofVec2f values, with a procedure along the lines of...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++) {
        ofVec2f verts[4];
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
            verts[k] = foo;
        }
        geometry[i][j] = verts;
    }
}
```

My question is, how do I pass this data structure to a function to update these values and have the array point to this new array of ofVec2f values? I imagine I will need to pass them via pointers but I'm not sure how to do it, especially since I have a fixed array on the stack.

Thanks! let me know if you need to see anything else.

Comment: Like everything else.  By pointer or reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it:

**1)** By reference:

```
void function(ofVec2f (&array)[24][30][4]);
```

**2)** By pointer:

```
void function(ofVec2f (*array)[30][4]);
```

**3)** Using templates, to pass array of any size:

```
template <size_t X, size_t Y, size_t Z>
void function(ofVec2f (&array)[X][Y][Z]);
```

Comment: @Collin Schupman It's worth mentioning, you might want to search stack for how 2d/3d arrays are laid out in memory, and what happens when you pass arrays by pointer (look for array decay)

Comment: A big part of the question is how to assign the value once inside the function, trying out options 1 and 2 and doing array[i][j] = newVertices gives me a compile time error of "ofVec2f is not assignable"

Comment: @CollinSchupman Show us `ofVec2f `, then. Did you defined assignment operator? Did you make it public?

Comment: @CollinSchupman you can't do `geometry[i][j] = verts;`, you should just forget about verts and make your loop do: `geometry[i][j][k] = foo;`

Comment: Oh, I haven't noticed that. @CollinSchupman Your array is 3-dimensional array. `geometry[i][j]` is an array of type `int[4]`. You cant assign `ofVec2f` to it.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek totally, RyanP's suggestion worked fine

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it by reference or pointer. If, like me, you find the syntax for reference-to-array a bit toxic you might like to use a `using` alias or a `typedef`:

```
using GeometryType = ofVec2f[24][30][4];    // C++11
//typedef ofVec2f GeometryType[24][30][4];  // C++98

void fillGeometry(GeometryType& geometry) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
        geometry[i][j][k].setX(0.0);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a `C++ 11` tag, which is required by this solution.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek I did say "or a typedef". I've updated to show how.

Answer (score 0):

Have you kept a reference to the old arrays anywhere? If not, why are you creating a new set of arrays and then pointing to them (and thus marking the old arrays for garbage collection)? Why not just assign the new values to the existing arrays?

```
for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) { (and thus 
     geometry[i][j][k] = foo;
}
```

Comment: Excellent point, the ofVec2f objects were already created, so my solution just goes through each one and updates the values